# Payment not received

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I received an email from a company about a payment,but my wallet has not received it.my wallet does not show any transactions,even unconfirmed transactions.what should I do?Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Were you supposed to receive a payment from that company prior to have receiving the email? If so, contact their support and ask them. If not, then the email was probably a scam or phishing attempt.